# How create several columns of CardViews

Tags: java, android, xml, android-cardview

I try create fragment with several columns of the `CardViews`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:cardElevation="2dp"
     app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
         <TextView
             android:text           = "column 1"
             android:layout_width   = "wrap_content"
             android:layout_height  = "wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text           = "column 2"
                    android:layout_width   = "wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height  = "wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

But I see only first `CardView` on full width. Second `CardViews` not shown.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `android:layout_weight="1"` in both cardviews